# How to enable Assign to someone else option for some signers within the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

If I have 3 signer A, B, C in one envelope and I want to enable option Assign to someone else (using allowReassign) for only A and B.

Is there any way to enable option for only one or two signers depending on condition rather than giving Assign to someone else option to all signers by  using allowReassign=true at envelope level.

Answer (score 0):

There is `no way` to restrict `Assign To Someone else` at the recipient level. If you know that Recipient A and B will assign it to someone else, then you can make them as `Specify Recipient` so that they can specify recipient next in routing order who needs to sign the document.